# Is the set of subrings of $\mathbb Z[X]$ countable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, ring-theory, integers, polynomial-rings

Initially, I was trying to look at the subrings of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. Since I have failed hard, I have tried to at least count them.

So I have tried to build an injection from $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ to the set of subrings of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. Since $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ is uncountable, we would have the set of subrings of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ uncountable too.

By associating the sequence $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ to the ring $\mathbb{Z}[1,p_1 e_1 X²,p_2 e_2 X^3,...]$ where $p_k$ is the $k$-th prime number and $e_k\in\{0,1\}$, it fails; for instance $\mathbb{Z}[1,2X²,3X^3,7X^5]$ is equal to $\mathbb{Z}[1,2X²,3X^3,7X^5,23X^{10}]$ because $X^{10}\in \mathbb{Z}[1,2X²,3X^3,7X^5]$ since $X^{10}=(7X^5 - (2X² * 3X^3))^2$.

I am unable to repair it, maybe it is flawed from the start.

Actually, I do not even know if the set of subrings of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is uncountable. If possible I would like a proof or a reference to a proof see since I am curious about its countability.

Comment: It is actually countable. Try to write it as the union of the polynomials of degree $k$ for varying $k$

Comment: @Exodd: It seems like your comment wants to show the ring itself is countable. That's not the question.

Comment: I think it is uncountable if and only if there is one subring which has no finite set of generators. Not quite sure about that, though. I assume you want subrings to contain $1?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews there‘s such a subring, e.g. $\Bbb Z[2X,2X^2,2X^3, \dots]$

Comment: Yes, subrings must contain 1, i.e. a ring is defined to have a multiplicative identity.

Comment: Then given any $S\subseteq \mathbb N^+,$ the subring $\mathbb Z[2x^k]_{k\in S}$ is a different ring, since the polynomials will have some elements whose coefficients are $2$ on $x^k$ for $k\in S,$ and coefficients all divisible by $4$ for $k\notin S.$ @LukasHeger

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Given $S\subseteq \mathbb N^+,$ let $R_S$ be the subring of polynomials $\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$ with the condition that $a_k$ is even for $k>0,$ and $a_k$ is divisible by $4$ for $k\in S.$ $a_0$ can be any integer.

This is obviously closed under addition and contains the identity. A little more work shows it is closed under multiplication.

Given two sets $S_1\neq S_2,$ we can find, for $k\in S_1\Delta S_2,$ that $2x^k$ is in exactly one of the $R_{S_i},$ where $\Delta$ is the symmetric difference.

So these subrings are all distinct.

Instead of $2,4$ we could use $d,ed$ for any pair $e,d>1$ and $e\mid d.$

---

This can be used to prove that $R[x]$ has uncountably many subrings for any commutative ring $R$ with an ideal $I$ where $I^2\neq I.$

Not sure about other cases, like $R=\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z.$ Seems like you might get only countably many in that case?

---

Indeed, another way to write the proof is to consider subrings of $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z[x],$ where the coefficients for $k>0$ are $0$ for $k\in S$ and and $2$ or $0$ for $k\notin S.$ Then we take the inverse images of the uncountable subrings of $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z [x]$ through the map $\mathbb Z[x]\to\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z[x].$

Comment: "A little more work" sounds like an understatement, but it's actually not. It is easy.

Comment: Yeah, it’s just annoying notation, and I was too lazy to write it out. @mr_e_man

Comment: The $d,ed$ thing confused me. I suggest reformulating it as $ce,ce^2$ for $e>1$ and $c\geq1$.

Comment: nice construction! (+1) the $R=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ case is also quite interesting, maybe worth asking as a separate question...

Comment: Question posted. @AtticusStonestrom https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4493489/7933

Comment: @ThomasAndrews just saw it! :) (+1 of course)